# PyEDA - replace node in expression

Tags: python, pyeda

Consider the following piece of PyEDA:

```
a, b, c = map(exprvar, 'abc')
f1 = And(a,Or(~a,b))
print(f1)
```

outputs:

```
And(a, Or(~a, b))
```

How can I replace the first `a` with `c`? `compose` replaces all instances of `a`:

```
f1.compose({a: c})
```

outputs:

```
And(c, Or(~c, b))
```

Comment: PyEDA is apparently not active at recent times, may be you want to switch to a (more) active library?